# Windows Server 2012 on KVM behaving as if Windows Key is getting hit repeatedly

Tags: kvm-virtualization, windows-server-2012

I've got a brand new install of Windows Server 2012 Essentials running on KVM on OpenSuse 12.2.  When I VNC in to the VM (using the VNC server provided by KVM, not one installed on the guest OS), it behaves as if the start button is being mashed repeatedly.  Specifically, it rapidly switches between the desktop and the Start screen, making the system unusable.

The only entry in the guest's XML file relating to the keyboard at all is 
`<graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes' listen='0.0.0.0' keymap='en-us'>`.  I have plenty of other Windows Server virtual machines on this hypervisor that do not have this problem, but they're all 2003 and 2008 R2.  This is the first 2012 VM I've put on it.

I have tried:

- Using a different VNC client on a different OS to see if maybe I had a stuck key on my VNC client.
- Running virt-manager directly on the hypervisor and connecting to the VM directly.
- Changing the graphics type between vnc and cirrus

Nothing has made any difference.  Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Does disabling "Pass special keys directly to VNC Server" help? (Property is on the Inputs tab.) Obviously not a permanent fix, just curious if it helps.

Comment: Even changing my VNC client to view only mode doesn't help.

Comment: If it happens in view-only mode, the problem is with the guest, not your VNC client(s). Reboot the guest.

Comment: Rebooting the guest didn't fix the problem.  I tried migrating the guest over to an older Ubuntu Server 10.04 KVM hypervisor, and it didn't make any difference.  That seems to rule out both the client and the hypervisor, leaving just the VM itself.  I'm kind of baffled because this is a brand spanking new install straight off the ISO from MSDN.  I even tried redownloading the ISO from MSDN and comparing md5 sums to see if mine had gotten corrupted somehow, but they matched.